# Index Selection in ListView created at runtime in Visual Basic (Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, listview, dynamic

I am trying to use a ListView box created at runtime and I am able to populate items but the SelectedIndexChanged event is not working. I know I am missing something really simple. Below is a minimal working example where I am creating the ListView on a button click and populating with a couple of items. When I select an item nothing happens in the SelectedIndexChanged event.

```vb
Public Class Form1

    Dim lstMylist As ListView

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        lstMylist = New ListView()
        lstMylist.Location = New Point(37, 312)
        lstMylist.Size = New Size(150, 150)
        Me.Controls.Add(lstMylist)
        lstMylist.View = View.SmallIcon

        Dim myListItem1 As ListViewItem
        myListItem1 = lstMylist.Items.Add("Item 1")
        Dim myListItem2 As ListViewItem
        myListItem2 = lstMylist.Items.Add("Item 2")
    End Sub

    Private Sub lstMylist_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        MessageBox.Show("I am here")
        Select Case lstMylist.FocusedItem.Index
            Case 0
                MessageBox.Show("item 1")
            Case 1
                MessageBox.Show("item 2")
            Case Else
                MessageBox.Show("invalid")
        End Select
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the event handler to the ListView SelectedIndexChanged event

```
lstMylist = New ListView()
lstMylist.Location = New Point(37, 312)
lstMylist.Size = New Size(150, 150)

' Add the event handler for the listview
AddHandler lstMyList.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf lstMylist_SelectedIndexChanged

Me.Controls.Add(lstMylist)
lstMylist.View = View.SmallIcon
```

As outlined by djv it is important to call RemoveHandler if you remove the ListView

```
RemoveHandler lstMyList.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf lstMylist_SelectedIndexChanged
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I should have asked sooner ...would have saved a lot of frustration

Answer (score 1):

Steve's answer will work. But an alternative is to simply make your ListView `WithEvents`

```
Dim WithEvents lstMylist As ListView
```

and add Handles to the method declaration

```
Private Sub lstMylist_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstMylist.SelectedIndexChanged
```

This is more a VB.NET way of doing things. `AddHandler` is similar to C# `Event += new EventHandler` syntax.

Note, if using `AddHandler`, a matching `RemoveHandler` should appear if the ListView is to be removed and added repeatedly.

Comment: thank you..I would like to learn this method.....Could you show me how I would use the RemoveHandler part?

Comment: That would go with Steve's answer. `RemoveHandler lstMyList.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf lstMylist_SelectedIndexChanged` should be called if the ListView is removed. If AddHandler is called twice then you will have two handlers, so make sure you remove the first prior to adding another one. My answer with the WithEvents and Handles doesn't require Add/RemoveHandler